# Не работает нижеследующая конструкция в условии, IDE считает, что здесь ошибка.

Tags: php, phpstorm

```
if(!empty(parse_url($location, PHP_URL_PATH)))
```

Насколько я помню, такой вариант использования вполне допустим, однако PHPStorm пишет, что здесь ошибка, то бишь ожидается переменная. Я его не понимаю, объясните, пожалуйста, почему так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Решено](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.empty.php)